# C/C++: Disable mouse in Linux (X11 - xinput)

Tags: c, linux, mouse, x11, xinput

I want to programmatically enable and disable the mouse in Linux using C/C++. There is the input extension for X11 that allows you to do it using the terminal command:

```
xinput set-int-prop "<device name>" "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

This works perfectly, but I'm looking to do this directly using a library. I can't find any proper documentation on libxi (X11 input extension library) and the header files in /usr/include/X11 also don't provide any useful functions. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do realize that `xinput` is open source, right? :) [Here's the source tree](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinput/tree/src).

It seems to boil down to a call to [`XIChangeProperty()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xichangeproperty).

You can probably read the code a bit more closely than I did, and the manual page of course, to figure out the required arguments.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, somehow missed that function. I'll dig into the code. Do you by any chance have a link to an example that uses this to disable a device? I found a couple of examples, but none of them properly explain the parameters or illustrate how to enable/disable devices. If not, I'll just go through the code in the xinput program.

Comment: Nope, I rarely program X11 directly so I don't have anything. I'm more of a GTK+ beard. :) The `xinput` source was short, you should easily be able to figure it out. Don't forget the documentation, either.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.

Comment: As a addition, ltrace command would be very useful to debug xinput and find what is executed when you enable/disable a mouse.